# Find number of selfloops and multilinks in a graph

Tags: r

I have a graph with *N* nodes and *E* links that may contain selfloops and multilinks.
How can I calculate the number of selfloops and the number of multilinks that it contains?

I created a graph in R and then I convert it into an adjacency matrix. 
I created a function that should calculate the two values but doesn't always work.

My code:

```
ident <- function(...) {
  args <- c(...) 
  if(length(args) > 2L) {
    # recursively call ident()
    out <- c(identical(args[1], args[2]), ident(args[-1]))
  }
  else {
    out <- identical(args[1], args[2])
  }    
  return(all(out))
}

net <- static.power.law.game(no.of.nodes = 10, 
                             no.of.edges = 15, 
                             exponent.out = 3, 
                             exponent.in = 3, 
                             loops = TRUE,
                             multiple = TRUE) 

netmatr <- as_adjacency_matrix(net) 

n_self_mul <- function(network_matrix) {
  selfloops <- 0
  multiarchi <- 0
  for(j in 1:nrow(network_matrix)) {
    if(ident(netmatr[j, j], 1)) {   
      selfloops <- selfloops + 1
    }
    for(i in 1:ncol(network_matrix)) {
      if(netmatr[i, j] > 1) { 
        multiarchi <- multiarchi + 1
      }
    }
  }
  ret <- list("self" = selfloops, "mul" = multiarchi)
  return (ret)
}
```

For example, if I have this [graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/djsRS.png), my function returns: selfloops = 2 and multilinks = 1.

How can I solve?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this very simply using the adjacency matrix. If a node has an edge to itself (a self-loop) than there will be a non-zero entry on the diagonal of the adjacency matrix. If there is a multi-link then there will be an entry in the adjacency matrix that is greater than 1.

Here is an example.

```
set.seed(42)
net <- static.power.law.game(no.of.nodes = 5,
                              no.of.edges = 10, 
                              exponent.out = 3, 
                              exponent.in = 3, 
                              loops = TRUE,
                              multiple = TRUE)

# Get the adjacency matrix. I like it with zeros (sparse=F) 
# but if your graph is really big leave sparse
netmatr <- as_adjacency_matrix(net, sparse=F)
netmatr
      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5]
[1,]    0    0    0    0    0
[2,]    0    0    0    0    0
[3,]    0    0    0    0    2
[4,]    0    0    0    2    1
[5,]    3    1    0    0    1
```

On this small example you can see by visual inspection that there are three multiedges ([3,5],[4,4] and [5,1]) and two self-loops at [4,4] and [5,5]. However, this can be computed as:

```
no.of.selfloops <- sum(diag(netmatr)) # This counts each edge in multi-edged self-loop
no.of.multilinks <- sum(netmatr>1)
```